# How do I access the key value of a Django ForeignKey field without a table lookup?

Tags: django, django-models

I have several models in Django with ForeignKey fields that are linked to models with meaningful (non-generated) primary keys. How can I set or get the ForeignKey field of an instance of such a model without forcing a table lookup to retrieve the actual object that is pointed to? Here's an example:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    iso = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        primary=True)
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=128,
        null=False,
        blank=False)

class Address(models.Model):
    street = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
```

I'd like to be able to set an instance of the Address class' `country` field to `'US'` and similarly, see that value (`'US'`) without having to say `address.country.iso` and (presumably) force a table lookup. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
address.country_id
```

To update:

```
address.country_id = 'UK'
address.save()
```

Maybe you will need to force update: `address.save(force_update=True)`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.